# How do I view my react app on my mobile iphone?

Tags: reactjs, server, ip

I have used this strategy before and it stopped working. To view a react app (not react native) on iphone I usually just run the server on my machine (in this case my laptop) and enter the ip address on my phone followed by a ":" and the port.

for example:

```
192.168.1.{the ending of the ip address}:3000
```

But when I do it this time it shows -> "Safari could not open this page because it could not connect to the server."

Comment: Is your phone connected to the same network as your laptop? A possible cause is you may have lost your wifi connection to the phone and have been using your mobile network instead.

Comment: Yes it is connected to the same wifi. I made sure of that.

Comment: Does Safari mention if it can't find the host or if it's a connection refused error?

Comment: As a good alternative you can use ngrok: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @Klaassiek I will try that!